# Trying to get data to display in a table

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on my first node project using express and sequelize, and I'm not understanding how the page rendering works

I have the following function in my one of my models(sequelize):

```
getGreetings: function (req, res) {
    Greeting.findAll({

    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log('Returned data for greetings: ' + data);
        res.send({greetings:data});
    })
}
```

Here is my route:

```
var Greeting = require('../models/greetings');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', function(){
        Greeting.getGreetings(req, res);
    });
});
```

and my ejs table I want to display the data in:

```
 <tbody>          
    <% for(var i=0; i < greetings.length; i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= greetings[i].name %></td>
        <td><%= greetings[i].message %></td>
      </tr>
    <% } %>
 </tbody>
```

This isn't displaying any of the html, but rather echoing out the json data. Can someone help explain why my html table isn't being populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but rather echoing out the json data.

This is because `getGreetings()` is always setting that as the response, by using [`res.send()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send):

```
res.send({greetings:data});
```

To provide `greetings` to your view, you'll have to instead provide the `data` within the `locals` given to [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render):

```
res.render('index', { greetings: data });
```

The two methods don't cooperate with each other. Each is defined to [end](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) the response itself, so you'll only be able to use one per response.

---

If you revise `getGreetings` to `return` the promise created by `.findAll()`:

```
getGreetings: function (req) {
    return Greeting.findAll({
        // ...
    });
}
```

Then, the route handler can bind to it and decide how to make use of the result itself – whether it should use `res.send()` or `res.render()`:

```
var Greeting = require('../models/greetings');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Greeting.getGreetings(req).then(function (greetings) {
        res.render('index', { greetings: greetings });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you also add a note about the router making use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-express. That would allow using try catch blocks and returning `next(err)` in case the promise fails. Thanks!